# Usage / meaning of the word "Defendee"

Tags: meaning

Defendee as far as I know means '*One who is defended*'.
Since English is not my mother's language, I am wondering if the word Defendee is usable/suitable for something like "**Self defense**" "**defend yourself**".

For a website I am working on a self-defense project, and I want to have a single dictionary word as a domain, associated with 'self defense'. People need to understand it immediately.

Comment: Thank you for the acceptance and I hope your self-defense enterprise goes well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my surprise, ***defendee*** is in the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/48791?redirectedFrom=defendee#eid)! I quote the entire entry because you may not be able to access it through the link.

> Origin: Formed within English, by derivation. Etymons: defend v., -ee
>   suffix1.
>
> Etymology:  < defend v. + -ee suffix1.   Compare earlier defendant n.,
>   defender n. rare.
>
> Categories »
>        **A person who is defended.** (emphasis added)
>
> 1811   Edinb. Rev. Aug. 331   The severe epithets which..Sir Patrick,
>   the defendee, would have been the first to bestow upon it.
>
> 1991   Pharos-Tribune (Logansport, Indiana)  5 Feb. a4/4   The
>   defendees are the likes of the American Nazi Party.
>
> 2002   D. Borgenicht & J. Borgenicht Action Hero's Handbk. i. 56
>   Push your defendee to the ground

To answer your question:  I don't think defendee is the word you want.  A defendee is a person who someone else defends.  A defendee is not someone who is defending himself or anyone else.  **Self-defenders** would be better.

I just read your comment under Willie Wheeler's answer.  I think you could use self-defendee.  It would be a little strange, but it is clearly related to self-defense.  **Self-defendant** is another and better possibility.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ab2!
So defendee would rather have a better fit for somebody like a lawyer? (who is defending someone, then he would be the defendee?)

Comment: @barry The lawyer is the defender.  His client is the defendee.  If  the lawyer's client is on trial, he is the defendant.  And there is an obsolete meaning of defendant which is someone defending himself.  self-defendant is used in a quote in the OED.

Answer (score 1):

"Defender" would be more typical than "defendee".

Comment: Thank you for your response. Defender(.com) as a domain is pretty impossible to get. Therefor I am wondering if 'Defendee' is also correct, ...not the best but still it does make sense..?

Comment: @barry Is your project based in the US and/or intended for international participation? If it isn't there's no need to register a .com domain so you could use your local domain categories (.co.uk or .org.uk for the UK, .co.au for Australia etc). I know this isn't an English Language answer but it might help.